# How to edit TabViewItem in UWP application

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp

I have a TabView, in Tabview has some TabviewItem. When I resize screen, Tabview auto hide TabviewItem and show "<" or ">". I can't edit style of "<" and ">", is there any solution for this?
Thanks and Regards
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLVaK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code of the TabView in the UWP Community toolkit, you'll see that the 2 buttons are defined in a Style `TabViewScrollViewer` here https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/4c24a314db876a93c79ca634590f6b0827a99a6a/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/TabView/TabView.xaml#L700

It are 2 RepeatButtons that use the Segoe MDL2 Asset. ( one for < and one for > )

You can override this template by copy / pasting this one into your own project and edit it.

I would also suggest adding an issue on github to ask for an extra hook on the TabView control to enable adding your own Segoe MDL2 Asset values for those 2 buttons, so that we don't need to override the Style.

Already added it myself ;) https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/36005341-enable-hooks-to-supply-own-segoe-mdl2-asset-value