# Showing Loading Spinner on TabViewItem UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, fluent, winui

I am trying to add a loading spinner to my UWP TabViewItem Header so that it should be layed out as that of web browsers are so that i can show that the tab is loading content

how would i go about doing this?

Comment: Do the same way like mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273207/how-to-edit-tabviewitem-in-uwp-application

Comment: That is an old answer about an outdated library and is for the TabView header not the TabViewItem header

Comment: The possible solution should be similar but more complicated to the answer in the link which @Ax1le shared.  You need to create a custom TabViewItem header with custom style and handle the event which controls the process ring to show and hide.

Comment: Just to clarify, the loading spinner should be where the icon of the tabviewitem is?